# C+: Destructor for same instance of an object called twice

Tags: c++, class, pointers, destructor

so basically I have some c++ code in VS2013 that looks like this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class Test_Class {
public:
    Test_Class() {
        printf("In Test_Class()\n");
        allocated_array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 64);
        printf("Allocated %p\n", allocated_array);
    }

    ~Test_Class() {
        printf("In ~Test_Class()\n");
        printf("Freeing %p\n", allocated_array);
        free(allocated_array);
        printf("Freed %p\n", allocated_array);
    }
private:
    int* allocated_array;
};

class Holder {
public:
    Holder() {
        printf("In Holder()\n");
        m_test_class = Test_Class();
    }

    ~Holder() {
        printf("In ~Holder()\n");
    }
private:
    Test_Class m_test_class;
};

class Game {
public:
    Game() {
        printf("In Game()\n");
        m_holder = Holder();
    }

    ~Game() {
        printf("In ~Game()");
    }
private:
    Holder m_holder;
};

int main()
{
    printf("In main()\n");
    Game game = Game();
    return 0;
}
```

That when ran, gives me this output:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/g8vCdIo.png]

What I'm wondering is, why is the destructor of the same Test_Class  object getting called twice before it crashes (due to trying to free the same pointer twice). I went through with the debugger, to make sure it wasn't just a new instance of the class that had been given the same pointer as the other object, and sure enough it was the exact same object.

I understand that since the Test_Class object is a member of Holder, that it would create a Test_Class object, then create another one and destroy the old one (which it seems to do), but this weird behaviour of calling the destructor on the same seems to occur when I make a member of type Holder in the Game class. Obviously there's something I'm missing.

Comment: is there any reason why you mix c and c++ memory managing?

Comment: You need to create a copy constructor that prints as well to see what is going on.  Do that and then check the results.

Comment: You're violating the Rule of Three.

Comment: take out the line `m_test_class = Test_Class();`, it is unnecessary and it causes your problem.  You should also disable (or implement) Test_Class's copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator so that if you do make this mistake then the compiler catches it.

Comment: @Kerrek SB did you meant the rule of five?

Comment: Btw this is not C++, it's C++CLI. They are not the same language.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot for the purposes of this question it could as well be plain C++ - only the `main` function signature gives you a clue here.

Comment: I think this is important to make a distinction between the two. They are fundamentally not the same language and it can have implication on the posted answer, even if the syntax is really similar. I won't post a question with a C tag when it's C++. Even if I did, the community would have corrected it, just like I did for this question.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is, that your compiler is not able to eliminate the copy assignment `Game game = Game();`.

The correct code would be `Game game;`.

What your code does is to construct an object as rvalue, assign it to a new object `game` that is a lvalue. So in this line `Game game = Game();` two objects are constructed and one of them is immediately destructed after assignment.

**Edit**:

The same holds for m_Holder and so on - of course.

Comment: An object cannot be an lvalue. Value categories are properties of *expressions*, not objects.

Answer (score 1):

You might benefit from instrumenting your class to see what's happening.  A technique I often use is to create a specific instrumentation class with static counters for each significant event.  Here's an example that is little more than a wrapper around a numeric type (specifically `double` in this case), but it illustrates the idea:

```
class Goofy
{
private:
    double num;
public:
    Goofy(double n = 0) : num(n) { ++constructions; }
    Goofy(const Goofy &g2) : num(g2.num) { ++copyconstructions; }
    Goofy(const Goofy &&g2) : num(g2.num) { ++moves; }
    ~Goofy() { ++destructions; }
    Goofy &operator=(const Goofy &g2) { num = g2.num; return *this; }
    Goofy &operator-=(const Goofy &g2) { num -= g2.num; return *this; }
    Goofy &operator+=(const Goofy &g2) { num += g2.num; return *this; }
    // none of the code below is needed by the new version of the function
    Goofy &operator*=(const Goofy &g2) { num *= g2.num; return *this; }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Goofy &g2) {
        return out << g2.num;
    }
    static void report(int line) {
        std::cout << "At line " << line
              << "\nconstructions = " << Goofy::constructions
              << "\n       copies = " << Goofy::copyconstructions
              << "\n        moves = " << Goofy::moves 
              << "\n destructions = " << Goofy::destructions 
              << "\n     existing = " << Goofy::constructions + 
                    Goofy::copyconstructions + Goofy::moves - 
                    Goofy::destructions
              << '\n';
    }
    static long constructions;
    static long copyconstructions;
    static long moves;
    static long destructions;
};

long Goofy::constructions = 0;
long Goofy::copyconstructions = 0;
long Goofy::moves = 0;
long Goofy::destructions = 0;
```

Here's an example of how it was used: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56532/kahan-summation/56592#56592

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong with your code, but I'm going to go with it anyways. You need to (at a minimum) implement the copy constructor and copy assignment operator. I would use `new`, `delete` and `swap` since this is C++ and not C. Something like this:

```
Test_Class() {
    allocated_array = new int[64];
}

~Test_Class() {
    delete[] allocated_array;
}

Test_Class(const Test_Class& rhs)
{
    allocated_array = new int[64];
    std::copy(&rhs.allocated_array[0], &rhs.allocated_array[0] + 64, &allocated_array[0]);
}

Test_Class& operator=(const Test_Class rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        Test_Class(rhs).swap(*this);
    }

    return *this;
}

void swap(Test_Class & s) throw()
{
    std::swap(this->allocated_array, s.allocated_array);
}
```